# Facebook API token expiration date

Tags: facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api, symfony

I'm working on an `API REST` with `Symfony3`, and I get from a mobile app an `access_token` (USER)

This token is valid, I can retrieve user profile, and i'm working on the expiration date.

```
$accessToken = new AccessToken($access_token);
```

With this, I can get infos about my token, and in the field `expiresAt` I have `NULL`.

What does that mean ? Token will never expirate ? I'm looking for a way to get a permanent token, or long-lived.

Thanks !

Comment: A lot late, but did you ever find any reason for this behavior? I'm getting an "un-representable DateTime" error when trying to do AddDays() to a token expiration date. This could be because I'm getting expiration time as null. It happens only in device, not in simulator.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to debug a Token is the Debugger, it should show the expire date correctly: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

User Tokens are valid for 2 hours, Extended User Tokens are valid for 60 days. There is no permanent User Token.

More information:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: With your tool, I can see 2 months in Expires. But when I look in my object AccessToken I have null. It's the point of my question, I already rode documentation

Comment: you should add more code to your question, it´s hard to say anything with that one liner. either way, you can trust the debugger - in most cases. and you want to get an extended token, that´s explained in the 2 links of my answer. you don´t really need to get the expire date in your app, you just need to handle the situation when the token is not valid anymore.